# Typescript: How to use an async closure as an addEventListener callback while adhering to the no-misused-promises rule?

Tags: typescript, async-await

The following code works as expected; it processes a `click` event and only allows a subsequent `click` event to occur once the current one is finished processing.

However, since the <s>[IIEF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)</s> closure is `async`, the return value is `Promise<void>`, which means that it breaks the [`no-misused-promises`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises/) rule with an error of `Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected`. Taking away the `async` is not an option because it would result in having to remove the `await` on `handleClick()`, which has resulted in improper throttling of the click events when tested.

```js
let processingClick = false;
  document.getElementById(wikiPageElementId)?.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!processingClick) {
      processingClick = true;
      // `await` needed here so that each event is processed synchronously.
      // Without `await`, any subsequent click could be processed asynchronously
      // while `handleClick()` is running.
      await handleClick(event.target);
      processingClick = false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: You could turn off [`checksVoidReturn`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises/#checksvoidreturn) only, which I'm guessing is the one that triggers here, but that's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: By the way, there is no IIFE here, just a closure. An IIFE would be if you called it immediately, but here it's bound as an event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an IIFE (or an async IIFE) here - using `.then` or `.finally` will work just as well. (Consider `.finally`, because it'll handle both successes and failures)

```
let processingClick = false;
document.getElementById(wikiPageElementId)?.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (processingClick) {
        return;
    }
    processingClick = true;
    handleClick(event.target)
        .finally(() => {
            processingClick = false;
        });
});
```

If you had to use an IIFE, you could declare it inside the click listener.

```
let processingClick = false;
document.getElementById(wikiPageElementId)?.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    void (async () => {
        if (!processingClick) {
            processingClick = true;
            await handleClick(event.target);
            processingClick = false;
        }
    })();
});
```

(though that may run afoul of other linting rules you may have - the `void` is needed for `no-floating-promises`, but you also might have `no-void` - which is why a better approach would be to avoid async IIFEs entirely)